# UIScrollView layout change

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipagecontrol

I have a UIScrollView with a bunch of images. So far I have managed to change the size of the scrollview and its UIImageViews when the layout changes. But the problem is that when the layout changes, the image seems to "swing" rather than rotate about its center point. This looks weird, I see many apps with such paging have implemented a smooth layout-change animation on the imageviews. How do I achieve this?

The code goes something like this:

```
viewDidLoad
{
     // Set up scrollview subviews and their content offsets based on NSArray

     // Set up orientation change listener
}

orientationChangeListener
{
     UIImageView *iv = [self.ivScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex: self.ivPager.currentPage];

     self.ivScrollView.layer.anchorPoint = iv.layer.anchorPoint;

     [self.ivScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(self.ivScrollView.frame.size.width * self.current, 0.0) animated:NO
 ];

    switch(orientation){

        case portrait:

              // update scrollview's subview sizes and content offsets
              // code to position the image appropriately based on screen dimensions

               break;

       case landscapeLeft:

              // update scrollview's subview sizes and content offsets
              // code to position the image appropriately based on screen dimensions

               break;

       case landscapeRight:

              // update scrollview's subview sizes and content offsets
              // code to position the image appropriately based on screen dimensions

               break;

    }

}
```

I hope that gives you the idea. :)

Comment: Code will be the most helpful, there's too many clarifications.

Comment: I've added an abstract code just to give you an idea. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, that should help. Is that correct that you are simulating paging of the images showing one of them ? I guess the view with an image is centered relative to the scroll view ? If that is correct, I'd expect anchorPoints to be (0.5, 0.5) for the scroll view and all it's subviews, do you explicitly change them anywhere ?

Comment: Well, yes, whenever the layout changes. I admit I don't have a good understanding of how the anchorPoint system works, in this case or any (I'm still a novice to iOS). Maybe you could provide me with a link with the appropriate explanation? :)

Comment: Sure, here's how I find it: [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint) > [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514) > [Layer Geometry and Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is in case someone faces this problem and happens to find this page:**

After a lot of research I finally solved this problem by following the instructions in this video [WWDC 2010 Video: Designing Apps with Scrolls Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/)

Also, after following everything in the video I had to set this property in each of the Zoomable scrollviews which displayed the images:

```
myZoomableScrollview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```